# How to Configure Elasticache in Single AZ

Tags: terraform, amazon-elasticache

I want to have an elasticache with all shards in single az `us-east-2a`. Since I already have an existing subnet_group "multi-az-subnet-group" which includes two subnets: `us-east-2a` and `us-east-2b`. so I just re-use it. but I set preferred_cache_cluster_azs with one az "us-east-2a". Here is the terraform code:

```
resource "aws_elasticache_replication_group" "test" {
  num_node_groups      =   var.num_node_groups
  subnet_group_name        = "multi-az-subnet-group"
  preferred_cache_cluster_azs  = ["us-east-2a", "us-east-2a"]
  ....
}
```

However, when I create the elasticache with only 1 shard, both primary and replica nodes are in the same az `us-east-2a`. But when I add one more shard, the primary and replica nodes of the 2nd shard go to different AZ.

To resolve that, I create another subnet_group "single-az-subnet-group", which includes only one subnet `us-east-2a`, and assign it to subnet_group_name of the elasticache, but terraform tries to recreate a new elasticache, which is not what I want. I want terraform to modify, rather than destroy the original elasticache. and I think since the first shard is already in `us-east-2a`, and subnet_group "single-az-subnet-group" only includes `us-east-2a`, then aws should be able to keep the elasticache in `us-east-2a` without destroying it.

Question: in this case, how to modify the terraform code so that I can add new shards in the same az `us-east-2a` without recreating the elasticache? Note, the primary and replica node of the first shard is already in `us-east-2a`.

Comment: That is not something related to terraform, rather which argument change results in the resource being recreated and it's the AWS provider that exhibits such behavior. If you take a look [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticache-replicationgroup.html) at the `CacheSubnetGroupName`, you will see that the change in the subnet group results in resource being recreated. I would guess there is a way to create a snapshot and then recreate everything the way you want.